# Dobble Cards Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm learning about list operations in Prolog. I thought computing a Dobble card set would be a fun exercise.

The card game Dobble (aka Spot It!) has 55 cards.
There are 57 symbols. Each card has 8 different symbols.
Any two cards have exactly one symbol in common.

I am using lists and numbers to represent the cards and symbols in Prolog. I wrote the predicates *isCard\1* and *oneMatch\2* to define what cards look like, and that two cards have exactly one symbol in common. I'm stuck at putting it together in *isDobble\1*. Prolog seems to calculate forever, and throws stack overflow errors.
Your advice is greatly appreciated!!

My goal is to query "*isDobble(X).*" and magically :) receive a valid Dobble card set.

```
isCard(C) :-                            % Card C has the right amount of allowed symbols if..
  length(C, 8),                         % card C has 8 symbols, and
  sublist(C, Sym),                      % symbols are a subset of allowed symbols, and
  findall(S, between(1, 57, S), Sym).   % allowed symbols range from 1 to 57.

oneMatch(A,B) :-                        % Card A and B have exactly one matching Symbol if..
  permutation(A, [AHead|ATail]),        % card A can be permutated, and
  permutation(B, [BHead|BTail]),        % card B can be permutated, such that
  AHead = BHead,                        % the first symbol of card A and B match, while
  ATail \= BTail.                       % any other symbol of card A and B do not match.

isDobble(D) :-                          % It's a Dobble card set D if..
  length(D, 55),                        % the number of cards is 55, and
  permutation(D, [DHead|DTail]),        % any card of the set
  maplist(oneMatch(DHead), DTail),      % matches exactly one symbol of any other card, and
  maplist(isCard, D).                   % any card has the right amount of allowed symbols.

isDobble(X).                            % Show me a Dobble card set X!
```

Comment: Algorithm hints at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52846660/

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you would have more than `2^225` of elementary computations free. Or say `2^2^225`. Would this really solve the problem?  Before going into any further detail and wasting one solar system after the other, I looked at a tiny part of your program, a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice):

```
isCard(C) :-
  length(C, 8),
  sublist(C, Sym), false,
  findall(S, between(1, 57, S), Sym).

?- isCard(C).
   loops.
```

This already does not terminate. To see this, take (using [that](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/dialect/sicstus/lists.pl?show=src#sublist/2) definition for `sublist/2`):

```
?- length(C,8), sublist(C,Sym). 
   C = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H], Sym = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H]
;  C = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H], Sym = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H,_I]
;  C = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H], Sym = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H,_I,_J]
;  C = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H], Sym = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H,_I,_J,_K]
;  C = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H], Sym = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H,_I,_J,_K,_L]
;  C = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H], Sym = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H,_I,_J,_K,_L,_M]
;  ... .
```

By exchanging the last two goals you could solve this somewhat. That is, you would have a terminating program, but one with a lot of solutions.

With `clpz/clpfd` you can collapse that large search space into a single answer:

```
:- use_module(library(clpz)).

isCard2(C) :-
   length(C, 8),
   C ins 1..57,
   chain(#<, C).

?- isCard2(C).
   C=[_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H],
   clpz:(_A#=<_B+ -1), clpz:(_B#=<_C+ -1), clpz:(_C#=<_D+ -1),
   clpz:(_D#=<_E+ -1), clpz:(_E#=<_F+ -1), clpz:(_F#=<_G+ -1),
   clpz:(_G#=<_H+ -1),
   clpz:(_A in 1..50),
   clpz:(_B in 2..51),
   clpz:(_C in 3..52),
   clpz:(_D in 4..53),
   clpz:(_E in 5..54),
   clpz:(_F in 6..55),
   clpz:(_G in 7..56),
   clpz:(_H in 8..57).
```

That is, with a single answer, you can represent all solutions compactly.

Answer (score 0):

> Prolog seems to calculate forever

Indeed!

From `?- help(permutation).` in SWI Prolog:

> Note that a list of length N has N! permutations, and unbounded permutation generation becomes prohibitively expensive, even for rather short lists (10! = 3,628,800).

```
length(D, 55)
permutation(D, [DHead|DTail])
```

Has `55!` loops to work through, which is

```
12696403353658275925965100847566516959580321051449436762275840000000000000
```

approximately 2<sup>243</sup>. [Thomas Pornin's answer about breaking encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6149/) estimates:

> the total mass of the Solar system, if converted in its entirety to energy [...] implies a hard limit of about 6.32×10<sup>68</sup> elementary computations, which is about 2^<sup>225.2</sup>

and that's 18 doublings less than you need; if you could perfectly efficiently use twenty entire Suns on a perfectly efficient computer, you would still need more energy because backtracking and list unification are not an elementary computations, and you have two more permutations still to do.

> My goal is to query "isDobble(X)." and magically :) receive a valid Dobble card set.

But then if your goal is magic, you may need some darker arts to cut through such a large search space; e.g. `clpfd`, but I suspect it would help more to [understand this math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobble) of the finite projective planes behind Dobble, links to [this explanation](https://puzzlewocky.com/games/the-math-of-spot-it/) and then code one and walk through it generating the cards. That links to [Python - Spot it! Cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492822/python-spot-it-cards) and [What are the mathematical/computational principles behind this game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240113/what-are-the-mathematical-computational-principles-behind-this-game) as well as @brebs' link to [Spot it algorithm - js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822827/spot-it-algorithm-js/52846660#52846660) from their comment.

Answer (score 0):

Can get part of the way (22 cards instead of 55), using [clpBNR](https://github.com/ridgeworks/clpBNR):

```
:- use_module(library(clpBNR)).
% Provide roughly 3.5GB RAM
:- set_prolog_flag(stack_limit, 3_647_483_648).

cards(Cards) :-
    % Should be 55
    length(Cards, 22),
    cards_(Cards, [], 1),
    enumerate(Cards).

cards_([], _, _).
cards_([Card|T], Upto, CardNum) :-
    length(Card, 8),
    % Seems efficient to order the numbers in each card
    ascending_distinct_bnr(Card),
    Card::integer(0, 56),
    count_matches(Upto, Card),
    CardNum1 is CardNum + 1,
    cards_(T, [Card|Upto], CardNum1).

% Match the new card with 1 symbol on the other cards
count_matches([], _).
count_matches([H|T], Card) :-
    count_matches_lists_bnr(H, Card, 1),
    count_matches(T, Card).

count_matches_lists_bnr([], _, 0).
count_matches_lists_bnr([H|T], L, Matches) :-
    [Matches, Matches0]::integer(0, _),
    count_matches_bnr(L, H, MatchesL),
    {Matches == Matches0 + MatchesL},
    count_matches_lists_bnr(T, L, Matches0).

count_matches_bnr([], _, 0).
count_matches_bnr([H|T], E, Matches) :-
    [Matches, Matches0]::integer(0, _),
    % (H == E) is Boolean, 1 (true) or 0
    {Matches == Matches0 + (H == E)},
    count_matches_bnr(T, E, Matches0).

ascending_distinct_bnr([H|T]) :-
    [H|T]::integer,
    ascending_distinct_bnr_(T, H).

ascending_distinct_bnr_([], _).
ascending_distinct_bnr_([H|T], Prev) :-
    {H > Prev},
    ascending_distinct_bnr_(T, H).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
% 23,849,152 inferences, 2.880 CPU in 2.886 seconds (100% CPU, 8280501 Lips)
C = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],[0,15,16,17,18,19,20,21],[0,22,23,24,25,26,27,28],[0,29,30,31,32,33,34,35],[0,36,37,38,39,40,41,42],[0,43,44,45,46,47,48,49],[0,50,51,52,53,54,55,56],[1,8,15,22,29,36,43,50],[1,9,16,23,30,37,44,51],[1,10,17,24,31,38,45,52],[1,11,18,25,32,39,46,53],[1,12,19,26,33,40,47,54],[1,13,20,27,34,41,48,55],[1,14,21,28,35,42,49,56],[2,8,16,24,32,40,48,56],[2,9,15,25,31,41,49,54],[2,10,18,22,30,42,47,55],[2,11,19,27,35,36,44,52],[2,12,17,28,34,37,43,53],[2,13,21,23,33,38,46,50],[2,14,20,26,29,39,45,51]] ;
```

This could of course be converted to use clpfd.

I added `CardNum` for future usage.

I found [salvi](http://salvi.chaosnet.org/snippet.html#dobble) site which links to [code](http://salvi.chaosnet.org/snippets/dobble.md), and its third (small) Prolog program results in:

```
?- time(dobble(8, C)).
% 4,862 inferences, 0.001 CPU in 0.001 seconds (99% CPU, 5412536 Lips)
C = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],[0,15,16,17,18,19,20,21],[0,22,23,24,25,26,27,28],[0,29,30,31,32,33,34,35],[0,36,37,38,39,40,41,42],[0,43,44,45,46,47,48,49],[0,50,51,52,53,54,55,56],[1,8,15,22,29,36,43,50],[1,9,16,23,30,37,44,51],[1,10,17,24,31,38,45,52],[1,11,18,25,32,39,46,53],[1,12,19,26,33,40,47,54],[1,13,20,27,34,41,48,55],[1,14,21,28,35,42,49,56],[2,8,16,24,32,40,48,56],[2,9,17,25,33,41,49,50],[2,10,18,26,34,42,43,51],[2,11,19,27,35,36,44,52],[2,12,20,28,29,37,45,53],[2,13,21,22,30,38,46,54],[2,14,15,23,31,39,47,55],[3,8,17,26,35,37,46,55],[3,9,18,27,29,38,47,56],[3,10,19,28,30,39,48,50],[3,11,20,22,31,40,49,51],[3,12,21,23,32,41,43,52],[3,13,15,24,33,42,44,53],[3,14,16,25,34,36,45,54],[4,8,18,28,31,41,44,54],[4,9,19,22,32,42,45,55],[4,10,20,23,33,36,46,56],[4,11,21,24,34,37,47,50],[4,12,15,25,35,38,48,51],[4,13,16,26,29,39,49,52],[4,14,17,27,30,40,43,53],[5,8,19,23,34,38,49,53],[5,9,20,24,35,39,43,54],[5,10,21,25,29,40,44,55],[5,11,15,26,30,41,45,56],[5,12,16,27,31,42,46,50],[5,13,17,28,32,36,47,51],[5,14,18,22,33,37,48,52],[6,8,20,25,30,42,47,52],[6,9,21,26,31,36,48,53],[6,10,15,27,32,37,49,54],[6,11,16,28,33,38,43,55],[6,12,17,22,34,39,44,56],[6,13,18,23,35,40,45,50],[6,14,19,24,29,41,46,51],[7,8,21,27,33,39,45,51],[7,9,15,28,34,40,46,52],[7,10,16,22,35,41,47,53],[7,11,17,23,29,42,48,54],[7,12,18,24,30,36,49,55],[7,13,19,25,31,37,43,56],[7,14,20,26,32,38,44,50]].
```

The above is 57 cards, so I removed the last 2 cards, and checked it works in my code (by setting `Cards` in my `cards/1` to the 55 8-number lists):

```
?- time(cards(C)).
% 39,438,078 inferences, 3.855 CPU in 3.860 seconds (100% CPU, 10230841 Lips)
```

Nice.

Comment: @repeat I don't know about better phrasing... find a woke person around you and ask them.

Comment: `% Provide roughly 3.5GB RAM` isn't something I would want to write in my code.

Comment: @TA_intern. I'm sorry, there aren't any. I tried again. Hopefully, I wrote something that offends nobody.